# C++ pointer pointer dereferencing

Tags: c++, pointers

how do i dereference this pointer-pointer, who holds data about a dynamically created 2D-array?

```
char **dog = new char *[480];
for (int i = 0; i < 480; i++)
    dog[i] = new char[640];
```

I know that the most left asterix holds the adresse information of the next right, but i struggle in accessing the value stored there (which is in the char[640] array).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find it easier to use `std::string` instead of `char*` as it hides its buffer pointer.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: If you are truly using C++ then use C++ data types (`std::vector<std::string>` in this case). If you are using C then re-tag your question.

Comment: @cdhowie The example code above is an answer to another question in the c++ forum on this site and I would like to understand pointers

Comment: @BenCollins I don't see why this is tagged as C - `new` is not a keyword in C.

Comment: @ace ah, you're right, I missed `new`.  However, cdhowie made a good point in that this is very un-idiomatic C++ (these days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you assign value to the first dog element as
    `strcpy(dog[0],"abcd");`

You access it as:
`dog[0][0]` gives `'a'`

`dog[0]` gives `"abcd"`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can just use:

```
char letter = dog[x][y];
```

to retrieve one letter.

or

```
char* dogName = dog[x];
```

to retrieve whole string.

Answer (score 1):

```
void main()
{
    char **dog = new char *[480];
    char * rupert = "Rupert_the_dog";

    dog[0] = rupert;

    std::cout << dog[0] << "   " << dog[0][1];

    system("pause");
}
```

Note that `dog[0]` outputs the entire string literal while `dog[0][1]` outputs the second letter, `'u'`. This is how you access the elements of the array since your array is holding char * pointers. However, given this example, do NOT try to do `dog[number > 0][1]` since it won't exist in this context.